# How do I write labels for codes in a html file with django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

In the Django 2.2 manual p 86 there is the following code:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
            ('S', 'Small'),
            ('M', 'Medium'),
            ('L', 'Large'),
                       )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHIRT_SIZES)
```

It then explains that I get something like 'L' by using p.shirt_size and 'Large' by using p.get_shirt_size_display().

But can I get that in an HTML-file? I get 'L' with {{ p.shirt_size }}, but if I want the actual description to be printed in the HTML-file, how do I do that? {{ p.get_shirt_size_display() }} does not work, does it? Which is the proper way to solve this problem?

Comment: You should omit the brackets, Django performs calls automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that as well, and nothing is printed in the HTML-file. Technically it is not this code, but i know the call corresponding to p.get_shirt_size_display() works in views.py. But not in the HTML-file. But if it should work, something else must be wrong.

Comment: Is the rest of the HTML code visibile? Are you sure you render the correct file? (Yeah I know that's a bit silly, but every now and then such things happen, and I've wasted some hours with such mistakes).

Comment: Yes, this is the only field that is blank. But knowing that it should work, I am sure there is a simple explanation which will strike down any day now.

Answer (score 2):

You are quite close. In case a field has a `choices=...` parameter, you can use the [**`get_fieldname_display()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) function to obtain the corresponding display of that choice.

Django's template language calls [callables automatically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#variables), so you should use:

```
{{ p.get_shirt_size_display }}
```

So omit the brackets.

Like the documentation specifies, such "variable" is [resolved in Django templates like](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#variables):

> **Behind the scenes**
>
> Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the
>   following lookups, in this order:
>
> 1. Dictionary lookup
> 2. Attribute or method lookup
> 3. Numeric index lookup
>
> **If the resulting value is callable, it is called with no arguments**. The result of the call becomes the template value.